# Cómo cambiar el input type dinámicamente

Tags: javascript, php, symfony

La idea es que si pulso tanto los operadores de id 25 y 26 se cambie el inputtype del input value. ¿Cómo hago con este js?

```
function changevaluefield(e){
    if (e.value == 25 || e.value == 26){
        if (document.getElementById(e.id.replace("operator","value")).type != "file"){
        document.getElementById(e.id.replace("operator","value")).classList.remove("form-control");
        document.getElementById(e.id.replace("operator","value")).classList.add("custom-file-input");
        document.getElementById(e.id.replace("operator","value")).type = "file";
        }
    }else{
        if (document.getElementById(e.id.replace("operator","value")).type != "text"){
            document.getElementById(e.id.replace("operator","value")).classList.remove("custom-file-input");
            document.getElementById(e.id.replace("operator","value")).classList.add("form-control");
            document.getElementById(e.id.replace("operator","value")).type = "text";
        }

    }
}
```

La idea es de cierto modo hacer esto dentro del php que he creado donde tengo un formulario personalizado y hacerlo mediante eventos, este es el formulario actual:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Form\Type;

class FiltercampaignvalueType extends AbstractType
{
    private $campaign;
    private $filtergroup;
    private $class;

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $this->campaign = $options['attr']['campaign'];
        $this->filtergroup = $options['attr']['filtergroup'];
        $this->class = 'row';
        $builder->add('fieldcampaign', EntityType::class, array(
                        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                                return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                                ->where('u.campaign = :campaign')
                                ->setParameter('campaign', $this->campaign)
                                ->orderBy('u.name', 'ASC');
                            },
                        'class' => Fieldcampaign::class,
                        'choice_label' => 'name',
                        'choice_value' => 'id',
                        'required' => true,
                        'label' => false,
                        'placeholder' => 'Choose a field',
                        'attr' => array(
                                'class' => 'fieldcampaign_select',
                                'onchange' => 'return preseclet(this);'
                        )
                    )
                );

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
                $data = $event->getData();
                $form = $event->getForm();

                if (!$data || null === $data->getId()) {
                        $form->add('operator', EntityType::class, array(
                                'class' => Operator::class,
                                'choice_label' => 'name',
                                'choice_value' => 'id',
                                'required' => true,
                                'label' => false,
                                'placeholder' => 'Choose an operator'
                                )
                        );
                }
        });

        $formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, Fieldtype $type = null) {
   
            $form->add('operator', EntityType::class, array(
                                'class' => Operator::class,
                                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($type) {
                                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                                        ->where('u.fieldtype = :fieldtype')
                                        ->setParameter('fieldtype', $type);
                                        //->orderBy('u.name', 'ASC');
                                },
                                'choice_label' => 'name',
                                'choice_value' => 'id',
                                'required' => true,
                                'label' => false,
                                'placeholder' => 'Choose an operator',
                                'attr' => array(
                                    'class' => 'valuefield',
                                    'onchange' => 'return changevaluefield(this);'
                                )
                                )
                        );

        };

        $builder->add('value', TextType::class, array (
                        'label' => 'Value',
                        'required' => false,
                        'label' => false,
                        'attr' => array(
                                'placeholder' => 'Insert value')
                    )
                );
        $builder->add('filtercampaigngroup', EntityType::class, array(
                        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                                return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                                ->where('u.id = :id')
                                ->setParameter('id', $this->filtergroup)
                                ->orderBy('u.name', 'ASC');
                            },
                        'class' => Filtercampaigngroup::class,
                        'label' => false,
                        'choice_label' => 'name',
                        'choice_value' => 'id',
                        'required' => true,
                        'attr' => array(
                            'readonly' => true,
                        )
                    )
                );
        $value="";
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
                
                $data = $event->getData();

                if($data !== null) {
                        if($data->getOperator() !== null) {
                            if ($data->getOperator()->getId() == 26 || $data->getOperator()->getId() == 25){
                                $value="file";
                                /*   $builder->add('value', TextType::class, array (
                                           'label' => 'Value',
                                           'required' => false,
                                           'label' => false,
                                           'attr' => array(
                                               'placeholder' => 'Insert value')
                                       )
                                   );*/
                            }else{
                                $value = "number";
                            }
                                $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data->getOperator()->getFieldtype());
                        } else {
                                $formModifier($event->getForm(), null);
                        }
                } else {

                        $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data);
                }
                
            }
        );
        if ($value == "file"){
            $builder->add('value', FileType::class, array (
                    'label' => 'Value',
                    'required' => false,
                    'label' => false,
                    'attr' => array(
                        'placeholder' => 'Insert File')
                )
            );
        }else{
            $builder->add('value', TextType::class, array (
                    'label' => 'Value',
                    'required' => false,
                    'label' => false,
                    'attr' => array(
                        'placeholder' => 'Insert value')
                )
            );
        }

        $builder->get('fieldcampaign')->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
               
                $type = $event->getForm()->getData()->getType();

                $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $type);
            }
        );

    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Filtercampaign::class,
            'csrf_protection' => false,
        ]);
    }

}
```

Aparte de lo que he puesto me gustaría también poder hacer que persista la información cuando hago los cambios tanto de el filtercampaign como de operator si es el mismo tipo el value.
Ahora mismo busco el poder hacer lo que hace el javascript pero mediante eventos de formulario de symfony: -Cambiar el type del input value a File cuando el input operator tiene id 25 o 26 y que vuelva a ser Text si es distinto a 25 y 26 y a poder ser que cuando cambio fieldcampaign no recargue todo el formulario dejando vacio el input value por ejemplo.

Comment: "no sé qué más escribir" <-- por ejemplo, podrías indicar cuál es el resultado esperado. No es claro qué buscas con la pregunta. O cuál es el error con el código que muestras. O qué pasa.

Comment: Ahora mismo busco el poder hacer lo que hace el javascript pero mediante eventos de formulario de symfony:
-Cambiar el type del input value a File cuando el input operator tiene id 25 o 26 y que vuelva a ser Text si es distinto a 25 y 26

Comment: Como te han dicho, en lugar de introducir ruido a la pregunta, indica el resultado esperado y el obtenido actualmente. Pulsa en [edit] para mejorarla.

Comment: @padaleiana lo he vuelto a editar cualquier cosa mal puesta o que querais que explique mejor me decis, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente el cambio de `input type` lo uso en campos como password cuando se requiere permitir al usuario evaluar su propia contraseña:

```js
function toglePassword()
{
  let e = document.getElementById("password");
  if (e.type === "password") {
    e.type = "text";
  } else {
    e.type = "password";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="password" id="password" value="">
<input type="button" value="Ver Contraseña" onclick="toglePassword()">
```

como podras ver simplemente se trabaja con la propiedad `type` del elemento.

Comment: si ves la parte de js lo tengo asi pero lo quiero cambiar ya que si lo hago asi al poner el type file se queda en blanco ya que necesita de un label si no me equivoco

Comment: no se si se pueden compartir imagenes por aqui si no te lo enseñaria

Comment: usa imgur o puedes editar y pegar la captura en tu post

Comment: https://imgur.com/LRLrXVP el hueco vacio es lo que deberia ser un input typeFile

Comment: no me queda claro ahora el contexto lo estas enrredando: tienes un input y ese input tiene un type, que type tiene y a cual quieres cambiarlo? en que evento quieres cambiarlo?

Comment: @Lennard señala el hueco, pero no tieen sentido cambiar un type file por un tipe text ... no va a funcionar ...

Comment: el type del input value puede ser text o file y debe ir cambiando dependiendo del input operator si el operator tiene el id 25 o 26 debe tener el type file el input value si el operator tiene seleccionado el valor distinto a 25 y 26 debe tener el type text el input value

Comment: la idea de cambiarlo de uno a otro es poder subir un ficehro para crear un filtro y si es un text normal usar el value que se escriba

Comment: y que tal si creas el type file y el text; uno oculto el otro visible y trabajas con la visibilidad en lugar del tipo???

Comment: el problema es que si lo tienes asi creado mediante symfony no lo relaciona a la entidad el que tenga un nombre distinto al campo de la base de datos

Comment: Se que es complicado pero en principio con los form eventes de symfony se debe de poder hacer lo unico es que no los he usado apenas y desconozco como hacerlo, si conoceis alguien que sepa bastante dee symfony y le comentais el problema me ayudariais bastante

Comment: tienes que manipularlo entonce, pero la entidad no puede ser de tipo text y tipo file al mismo tiempo...

Comment: tendrías que trabajarlo full text y si es file, usar el path que consideres para guardarlo en la entidad... ese si seria un string

Comment: A ver que no puede ser los dos a la vez lo se pero pensaba que con los eventos de form de symfony se podria recargar de cierta manera el form sin recargar la pagina

Comment: synfony es un framework que se ejecuta en php en el backend; como piensas comunicar al php con el html? si no haces algo con ajax/javascript no funcionara.